# Better way to reselect a multiple choice list with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to become a better PHP coder. The solution I found works (below) but look like it is not the best way to go about this. Can any better developers come up a better way to reselect items in a multiple select list using an array from the database that is more universally usable? Thanks for helping me become a better developer.

```
<?php
$optFood = '';
$optMedication = '';
$optVaccinations = '';
$optMedicalServices = '';
$optVaccinations = '';
$optOutdoorHousing = '';
$optOther = '';

$options = explode(",", mysql_result($call, 0, 'assistNeeds'));
foreach($options as $val) {
${"opt".str_replace(' (See Notes)','',str_replace(' ','',$val))} = "selected=\"selected\"";
}
?>

<select name="assistNeeds[]" size="6" multiple class="span2" id="assistNeeds" tabindex="12" title="Select All">                                      
<option <?php echo $optFood ?> value="Food">Food</option>
<option <?php echo $optMedication ?> value="Medication">Medication</option>
<option <?php echo $optMedicalServices ?> value="Medical Services">Medical Services</option>
<option <?php echo $optVaccinations ?> value="Vaccinations">Vaccinations</option>
<option <?php echo $optOutdoorHousing ?> value="Outdoor Housing">Outdoor Housing</option>
<option <?php echo $optOther ?> value="Other (See Notes)">Other (See Notes)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It looks like you have some messy data, but other than the string scrubbing you have to do, your method is as good as any.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: Thanks, I am converting most of it over to PDO right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify it using a foreach loop to create the options from an array `$assistNeeds`.

```
<select name="assistNeeds[]" size="6" multiple="multiple" class="span2" id="assistNeeds" tabindex="12" title="Select All">
<?php
  $options = explode(",", mysql_result($call, 0, 'assistNeeds'));
  $assistNeeds = array("Food","Medication","Medical Services","Vaccinations","Outdoor Housing","Other (See Notes)");
  foreach($assistNeeds as $option) {
      $selected = (in_array($option, $options)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
      echo '<option'.$selected.' value="'.$option.'">'.$option.'</option>';
  }
?>
</select>
```

this phpfiddle - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kkb-4q2 - uses `$options = explode(",", "Food,Vaccinations");` in the example